# HDRI Reflection not showing in render

Tags: rendering, materials, hdri, reflection

this most likely has a very simple answer but i can't find the answer anywhere online. I'm trying to get the reflection from the standard blender hdri on an object. It shows it perfectly in Look Dev mode, but in Rendered it just doesn't show up. I tried shifting the lighting, increasing light strength, etc etc. basically everything i could find but it's just not changing. What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: the look dev mode has a different lighting set up, you have to add the hdri to the render lighting set up, i  can show you if you want.

Comment: That would be great :)

Comment: Thanks guys, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

to add an hdri go to the `world` tab and add an environment node to the surface output, you can copy my basic setup it gives you some flexibility.
[image]